# Using Promise.all to execute a function after other ones

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to execute my function HideEmptyTile once all the previous functions are finished.

I was using TimeOut until now but this is not really a proper way to do what I want to accomplish.

Here is my previous code :

```
        retrieveAccountOpenWithVisitObjectif(userId, processOpenWithVisitObjectif);
        retrieveAccountOpen(userId, processAccountOpen);
        retrieveAllActivitiesOpen(userId, processAllActivitiesOpen);
        setTimeout("HideEmptyTile()", 800);
```

After few researches I found that I could use an other callback function, but it seems that Promise.all as been build for my case. So I did the next code :

```
Promise.all(
        retrieveAccountOpenWithVisitObjectif(userId, processOpenWithVisitObjectif),
        retrieveAccountOpen(userId, processAccountOpen),
        retrieveAllActivitiesOpen(userId, processAllActivitiesOpen)).then(HideEmptyTile());
```

The issue is that this is not the behaviour that I would like to have since the function HideEmptyTile is not executed after the other functions.

Am I using Promise.all in the wrong way?

Comment: You're calling `HideEmptyTile` when passing it to `then`. Take out the `()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `Promise.all` takes an array of promises, not multiple arguments
- `then` takes a function (you were already calling it and passing the result)

```
Promise.all([
    retrieveAccountOpenWithVisitObjectif(userId, processOpenWithVisitObjectif),
    retrieveAccountOpen(userId, processAccountOpen),
    retrieveAllActivitiesOpen(userId, processAllActivitiesOpen)
]).then(HideEmptyTile);
```

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure all your functions returns promise, then you will achieve your goal by:

```
var promises = [
    retrieveAccountOpenWithVisitObjectif(userId, processOpenWithVisitObjectif),
    retrieveAccountOpen(userId, processAccountOpen),
    retrieveAllActivitiesOpen(userId, processAllActivitiesOpen)
];

Promise.all(promises).then(() => HideEmptyTitle());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `Promise.all` takes an array to fulfill the promises.
2. You are passing the `HideEmptyTile()`in the `then` block. You need to pass inside the callBack:

```js
Promise.all([
        retrieveAccountOpenWithVisitObjectif(userId, processOpenWithVisitObjectif),
        retrieveAccountOpen(userId, processAccountOpen),
        retrieveAllActivitiesOpen(userId, processAllActivitiesOpen)]).then(function(){
          HideEmptyTile();
        });
```